# Unable to open a specif worksheet from VB.NET (What is wrong with this code?)

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
Private Sub Button11_Click()
    Dim oXL4 As New Excel.Application
    Dim oWB4 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet4 As Excel.Worksheet
If ComboBox10.Text = "abc" Then
    oWB4 = oXL4.Workbooks.Open("D:\blah\blah\Def.xlsx")
    oSheet4 = oWB4.Worksheets(2).Activate
    oXL4.Visible = True
    oXL4.UserControl = True
End If
End Sub
```

Error/Exception:

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'.

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate does not return a worksheet (it's a sub).

```
  oSheet4 = oWB4.Worksheets(2)
  oSheet4.Activate()
```